# R iterations only saving the first value of a vector

Tags: r

Up until now I find any problem I have has been had and posted here already, but this time I'm really at a loss.
I am running grep in R to look for a list of regex values in two strings, and write the ones that are exclusive to one string and not the other. The outputs are vectors, but when I loop through the vectors or even just try to save them, R is only saving the first value of the vector.

So while:

```
inWT = as.list(rep(0, nrow(NEBres)))

> c(setdiff(c(grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], reverseComplement(bigfile$FASTA, case = "upper")),
  grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], bigfile$FASTA)),
c(grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], reverseComplement(bigfile$m_FASTA, case = "upper")),
  grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], bigfile$m_FASTA))))

>[1]  86 480
```

if I try to save it it only saves the first value as so:

```
inWT[1] = c(setdiff(c(grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], reverseComplement(bigfile$FASTA, case = "upper")),
  grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], bigfile$FASTA)),
c(grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], reverseComplement(bigfile$m_FASTA, case = "upper")),
  grep(NEBres$Recognition_Site[1], bigfile$m_FASTA))))

> inWT[1]
[[1]]
[1] 86
```

I haven't been able to manage this solution for some time now, and I'm starting to run out of solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `inWT[[1]] = ` instead of `inWT[1] = `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.